# What preposition should be used with the 'wrap' verb?

Tags: prepositions

- I want to wrap it WITH the paper
- I want to wrap it IN the paper
- I want to wrap it BY the paper

Comment: In fact, it is the paper that you *wrap*, not the 'it'. So if at all the structure is to be used, the preposition could be **in**: *wrap it **in** paper*, in a roundabout way, sort of. That's because *wrap* can also mean 'have something wrapped in a sheet of paper or other material.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap is used as a **transitive verb**, an **intransitive verb** and a **noun**.

As a **transitive verb**, you wrap something in/by something else or for someone.
For example:

To wrap something IN paper = to use paper to surround something completely (denotes enclosure of one thing by another).
To wrap something BY something = to conduct the wrapping beside something else (denotes a position in space).
To wrap something FOR someone = to conduct the wrapping with a particular intention which relates to another person (denotes an intention).

As an **intransitive verb**, you wrap up something, meaning to finish or end it.
For example:

We have to wrap up the meeting at 4 o'clock sharp.

The most common uses of 'wrap' + 'with' are where 'wrap' is used as a **noun**, to denote a rolled-up sandwich, or a shawl, for example.
You'll find plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wrap%20with%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&safe=active) and [here](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?start=10&q=wrap%20with&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).